# Push on gerrit with windows

Tags: windows, git, repository, gerrit

I am struggling to push some of my data to a gerrit with TortoiseGit. I created a new repo and committed it to the master. I added one remote, with my private key and I also uploaded the public key.

Pulling from the gerrit is no problem, but when I try to push the following error occurs:

```
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (96/96)
remote: Processing changes: refs: 1, done    
remote: ERROR: missing Change-Id in commit message
remote: Suggestion for commit message:
remote: Initial Commit
remote:
remote: Change-Id: Icb5f79b9a32abc77a99f0034ecc6a5a9ae9ef1c6
remote: Hint: To automatically add a Change-Id to commit messages, install the commit-msg hook:
remote: $ scp -p -P 29418 <server stuff>:hooks/commit-msg .git/hooks/
```

The big problem is, I am living in a windows world, where is no $ scp .... any suggestions, how I can install git hook or delivering a commit id?

Btw `git hooks --install` returns `'hooks' is not a git command`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just download it from : `http://www.example.com/r/tools/hooks/commit-msg` and then copy it to your .git/hooks folder.

Or you can download it from [gerrit review](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/tools/hooks/commit-msg)

-- Update --

If you add the commit hook after making the commit locally, which is probably the case, you need to amend your last commit. Simply amending the last commit without making any real change will add the Change-ID to your log message.

1. `git commit -a --amend`
2. `git log -1` // this is to check that the Change-ID is present in your log message
3. `git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master`

-- Update 2 --

If you are like me and have a lot of projects at create clones every now and then you might want to setup your git installation so the commit-msg hook is installed by default. You can do this by copying the commit-msg to your git template folder. On my Win7 system it can be found here:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\share\git-core\templates\hooks`

The next time you create a new clone you do not need to download the commit-msg again.

Comment: Basically you can download the commit-msg script in the tools/hooks directory from your gerrit installation. As I didn't know your URL I put the example.com. I think this should solve your issue. Please accept the answer.

Comment: If I download the commit-msg from gerrit-review and copy it into `<Project Folder>\.git\hooks` it isn't working. I still get the same error message.

Comment: Ahh...the `commit-msg` hooks are shell scripts...they wont work on Windows machine

Comment: They DO work on windows. One thing you should do is amend your last commit, even if there is no change. By amending you last commit the change ID will be added to you commit message and after this you can push your commit for review. Simply do: git commit -a --amend and just save your previous text, then check with git log -1 to see if the Change-ID has been added.

Comment: I added some info about the git templates\hooks folder. This makes it much easier if you work with Gerrit regularly. Once you set it up you never need to worry about the commit-msg again

Comment: On windows10 the template folder location for me was: c:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\share\git-core\templates\hooks\.

Comment: For Unix users: if you download and copy manually the hook remember to run `chmod +x .git/hooks/commit-msg`. Otherwise it won't be executed.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a case of appropriate hooks not downloaded into your clone.

You can try doing this:

```
# cd into your clone such that you should be able to see .git folder on ls -a
# for example if you had following structure myclone/myproject/.git
# you have to cd to myclone/myproject directory


$ scp -p -P 29418 <server stuff>:hooks/commit-msg .git/hooks/
```

Now go to your hooks folder and do `ls` to see if you have required hooks downloaded.

You don't install any hooks you just copy it from your gerrit repo

**Update**
https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Talk:Gerrit/git-review
is what you are perhaps looking for

Comment: you just need to copy that commit-msg file to your .git/hooks directory..I am not sure if you have permissions to install software on your windows machine...but if you could...install `putty` or you could use `Win-scp` as well...or you could ask the admin to `email` it to you and you could copy it